# fscanf stops reading from text file after the 254th row of data

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to compile my data into a single file. The data can contain up to 10ish files, and each set would have 3 files, each named "vis11, vis12, &vis13" for the first set, and "vis21, vis22, & vis23" for the second.

The files have two columns of data, the first column showing the time, and the second column, a set of raw measured data. For example:

```
    0.00,   1.821
    1.00,   1.821
    2.00,   1.821
    3.00,   1.816
    4.00,   1.811
    5.00,   1.806
    6.00,   1.805
    7.00,   1.804
    8.00,   1.803
    9.00,   1.834
   10.00,   1.864
   11.00,   1.895
   12.00,   1.914
   13.00,   1.933
   14.00,   1.952
   15.00,   1.926
   16.00,   1.901
   17.00,   1.875
   18.00,   1.873
   19.00,   1.871
   20.00,   1.869
   21.00,   1.898
```

The program is supposed to open the first file (vis11) read the first row, copy it into an array, close it, open the second (vis12) read the first row, and catenate that string onto the same array, and on the 3rd file, and on to the next row and so on.

I've tried using different files, which has the same problem, so i don't believe its an issue with the file, nor is there a sudden change in format on the 254th line. i've also tried the program on .csv files, which has the exact same problem.

```
int n,i, j, ii, ff, r, rr, nn, b, ee, oo, Visnn=0, Uvnn=0;
float Vis, Uv, Visn, Uvn, TS;
char Stop[30]="Stop", Odd[30], DataRow[300], DataRow1[300], TimeStamp[300];

printf("Number of files:");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Vis Time:");
scanf("%f", &Vis);
printf("Vis Elements:");
scanf("%f", &Visn);
printf("Uv Time:");
scanf("%f", &Uv);

nn=Visn;

FILE*fpointer1;
fpointer1=fopen("Com.txt","w");  
fclose(fpointer1);


for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for(ff=1; ff<=nn;ff++){
        for(j=1;j<=3;j++){
            printf("\n \n");
            memset(Odd, 0, sizeof(Odd));
            sprintf(Odd,"Vis%d%d.csv",i,j);
            printf("Opening %s \n",Odd);

            FILE*fpointer;
            fpointer=fopen(Odd,"r");

            printf("j=: %d \n",j);

            if(j==1){
                printf("j=1 Detected \n");
                memset(DataRow, 0, sizeof(DataRow));

                for (ii=0 ; ii < ff; ii++)/*move through lines without scanning*/{
                    if(ii>0){
                    fscanf(fpointer, "%*s");
                    fscanf(fpointer, "%*s");
                    }
                }
                memset(DataRow1, 0, sizeof(DataRow1));
                fscanf(fpointer,"%s", &DataRow1);
                fclose(fpointer);
                strcat(DataRow, DataRow1);
            }

            FILE*fpointerd;
            fpointerd=fopen(Odd,"r");

            for (ii=0 ; ii < ff; ii++)/*move through lines without scanning*/{
                fscanf(fpointerd, "%*s");
                if(ii>0){
                    fscanf(fpointerd, "%*s");
                }
            }
            memset(DataRow1, 0, sizeof(DataRow1));
            printf("Before DataRow1: %s \n", DataRow1);
            fscanf(fpointerd,"%s", &DataRow1);
            printf("After DataRow1: %s \n", DataRow1);
            fclose(fpointerd);
            printf("Before DataRow: %s \n", DataRow);

            strcat(DataRow, DataRow1);

            strcat(DataRow, ",");

            printf("DataRow=%s \n", DataRow);



        }
    }
}






printf("Process completed, press ANY key to exit. \n");
getchar();   
getchar();
```

The program runs fine for small data sets, but runs into a problem when compiling files with more than 253 rows.

The fscanf function would stop reading anything once the program reaches the 254 row of the second file vis12. It doesn't read a wrong value, it just doesn't read anything.

Comment: first thing, why `scanf("%f", &Visn);`? why you read numbers as `float`?

Comment: Why shouldn't they read numbers as `float`s, @Afshin?  I mean sure, they could adjust the variable *and format* to read `double`s instead, but there's no inherent reason why they shouldn't read `float`s if that's what they want to do.

Comment: It's not clear what your issue may be.  We'll need a [mre] to do more than guess.

Comment: @JohnBollinger since it is number of elements, it is more logical to be `int` rather than `float`. Or it is at least what I got from code.

Comment: ahhsai, If code checked the return value of each `fscanf();`, the answer would be apparent.

Comment: @Afshin The reason why i wanted float was because i intended to do something with the variable Visn later on which won't be accurate enough as int.

Thanks all for your help, the issue was with me leaving one of the fopen outside an if() and the corresponding fclose inside the if() as pointed out by rtoijala. Fixed it and it's now all fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are leaking file handles. Consider the lines

```
FILE*fpointer;
fpointer=fopen(Odd,"r");
```

You open the file regardless of the value of `j`, but you only close it when `j == 1`. This means that two times out of three, you leak a file handle. Your operating system very likely has a limit on the number of open file handles you can have. When you reach that limit, `fopen` fails and returns `NULL`. Indeed, then you can check the value of `errno`, which for me was `24 == ENFILE` (too many open files).

The fix is to move the above lines into the `if (j == 1) { ... }` block, so that the file is opened only when it is needed.

Comment: Your right, it works perfectly now with the corrections you suggested. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. To make the code clearer (and probably much faster), I would suggest that you open each file only once. Open the file, gather the data into memory (an array allocated with `malloc`), close the file. Do the same with the other 2 files, then write the gathered data to where-ever you need it. That way you don't need to worry about skipping the already handled lines.